# Configurar proxy en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es configurar el proxy de ubuntu para darle salida a aplicaciones que no tienen configuracion por defecto de proxy. Lo que he hecho a sido ir a etc/enviroment y escribir:

```
https_proxy=https://jogarcia:18mypassword*@myproxy:3128
```

y asi para los otros protocolos pero no me funciona. Alguien sabe que debo hacer para hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Esto lo hago en windows con proxy cap con https, si saben de algún software en linux que tenga la misma función y permita usar https tambien me serviría

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta no encaja del todo con el sitio, te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), allí es más posible que tengas solución a tu problema